# Run multiple SHELL commands within same SHELL

Tags: perl

I am working on a legacy and confined system, where I do not have any known way to get anything installed. Now, I need to run multiple SHELL commands on a same shell.  For example, the 2nd command should be aware of any changes done to the SHELL environment by the previous command. (like Environment variable manipulation). The system does not have `perl expect` module available, so I am trying to use `IPC::Open3` to open shell and run commands and checking the stdout and stderr for expected strings. This works fine, for only the first function call of `runner` function and not the 2nd call.

Here is my code, dumb down version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IPC::Open3;
use utf8;

#First expect script

my $pid = open3(*IN, *OUT, *ERR, "/bin/bash");

my @output_arr;
my @error_arr;

sub runner {
  my ($PID,$CMD,$REGEX) = @_;
  print IN "$CMD\n";
  close IN;
  waitpid $PID, 0;
  my $cmd_output = do { local $/; <OUT> };
  my $cmd_error = do { local $/; <ERR> };
  if ($cmd_output =~ m/$REGEX/ or $cmd_error =~ m/$REGEX/) {
      print "$CMD output contains $REGEX\n"
  }
  else
  {
      print "$CMD output does not contain $REGEX, command output is $cmd_output ,error is $cmd_error\n"

  }
  push @output_arr, $cmd_output;
  push @error_arr, $cmd_error;
  return ($cmd_output, $cmd_error);
}


# This data will come from other progams. 
#this works
my ($date_output, $date_error) = runner($pid, "LC_ALL=C date", qr/2023/s);
#this never works
my ($date_output, $date_error) = runner($pid, "LC_ALL=C date", qr/Jan/s);
```

The output:

```
LC_ALL=C date output contains (?^s:2023)
LC_ALL=C date output does not contain (?^s:Jan), command output is  ,error is
```

Comment: Don't use `open3` if you're going to read and write from the process, or if you're going to read from two handles from the child process. (You do both!) To do so correctly requires using something like IO::Select as well, and it's quite complicated. Use IPC::Run with vars (`'<', \$stdin, '>', \my $stdout`) or callbacks (`'<', \&producer, '>', \&consumer`) instead. (You'd need the latter.) Note that you want to trick the child into flushing its output, so you will need pseudo-ttys. (`>pty>` instead of `>`).

Comment: In this particular case, it would make even more sense to use Expect. (It even uses pseudo-ttys.)

Comment: Re "*for only the first function call of runner*", yeah, you're tring to write to a handle you closed...

Comment: Do you really run without `use warnings;` and `use strict;` ?  I suppose that they're dropped here for ... brevity?, but let me say it just in case: those must be present on top of the file in every program. Also (not that it's needed), I second `IPC::Run` recommendation (learning how to use it is a great investment, which btw will pay off already on a project like this)

Comment: yes `use warning` and `use strict` are removed from this example for keeping it short.